# Relationships don't show in neo4j web browser when created by api...neo4j 2.0.1

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created a simple test in the java api (see below). I then set the neo4j-server.properties to that db and restart neo4j. I'm expecting to see two nodes and a relationship using the web browser localhost:7474/browser.

When code below is executed, the for loop does detect a relationship, however it does not display (nor are they returned by CYPHER query) in the browser.

I'm using 2.0.1 in the java and neo4j server. Is my expectation in error?

```
Transaction tx = gdb.beginTx();
    try
    {
     Label courseLabel = DynamicLabel.label( "Book" );
     Label courseLabelP = DynamicLabel.label( "Person" );
     Node a = gdb.createNode(courseLabel), b = gdb.createNode(courseLabelP);
     Relationship rel = a.createRelationshipTo( b, CourseRelTypes.HAS_AUTHOR );
        for(Relationship r : b.getRelationships(CourseRelTypes.HAS_AUTHOR)) {
            System.out.println("has rel");
          }
    }
    finally {
        tx.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a tx.success() to commit that transaction